# Mod_rewrite not working after moving site to a subfolder

Tags: html, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I just moved an old site to a subfolder along with it's mod_rewrite rules, but they don't work anymore.

One rule, for example is:

```
#   Input:  noticias/
#   Output: noticias.php
RewriteRule ^noticias/?$  noticias.php
```

It should go from mydomain.com/movedsite/noticias/ to mydomain.com/movedsite/noticias.php

It doesn't: the error message says

Not Found - The requested URL /mydomainfolder/movedsite/noticias.php was not found on this server.

I tried adding slashes in front of the elements of my rule, as suggested in another forum question:

RewriteRule ^/noticias/?$  /noticias.php

That doesn't work either.

Could anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set the RewriteBase:

> This directive is required when you use a relative path in a
> substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless either of the
> following conditions are true:
>
> - The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the
>   DocumentRoot (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as Alias).
> - The filesystem path to the directory containing the RewriteRule,
>   suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on
>   the server (this is rare).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase